# C++ Using a local variable of a method in another method

Tags: c++, reference

Does anyone know if there's a way to pass a variable that i have created inside of a method to another method . I am posting part of the code so that it is clearer what i need to do

```
int Point::trovaLato(Point *spigolo2, Point *sol_p, Point *pvet){
//code
//code
Point* lato=new Point(myvalue1,myvalue2,myvalue3);
return 0;
}
```

Now i want to use that variable 'lato' inside of

```
int Rettangolo::interseca(Point *sol_p, Point *pvet){
int ritlat, test;
test = punti[0]->trovaLato(punti[1], sol_p, pvet); //this works
if(test){
    test = punti[1]->trovaLato(punti[2], sol_p, pvet);//ok
    if(!test){
        ritlat = lato->intersecaLato(punti[1], punti[2]); //doesn't know what lato is ofcourse :(
//more code
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type to `Point`, and return one:

```
Point Point::trovaLato(Point* spigolo2, Point* sol_p, Point* pvet){
  //code
  //code
  return Point(myvalue1, myvalue2, myvalue3);
}
```

If you really need to return an `int`, you can return an `std::pair<int, Point>`.

Comment: I put 0 or 1 as return to tell me if the function found the intersection point or it didn't (which is what it does)

Comment: You can return a sentinel `Point` value to indicate failure. Or an optional object. There are different approaches to solve this.

Comment: the content of lato could be anything so i wouldn't know what to use as sentinel 
I have never used std::pair but looks like it could work. It lets me return different type. but what do i write? like
    return std::make_pair(0, lato); ?

Comment: @squirrel Right. Then check thr pair's `fist`, and use it's `second` if the `first` indicates an intersection. But maybe use a `bool` instead of an `int`.

Comment: well it gives me an error in the header file: 'pair' in namespace 'std' does not name a type

Comment: what do you mean ? where to use a bool?

Comment: fixed by adding #include <utility>

Comment: @squirrel I meant, if your `int` can only be 0 or 1, you could use a `bool` instead, so `std::pair<bool, Point>`. It is a detail,  but it would make code easier to understand because an int can hold many values, a `bool` can only hold two.